# How do I ignore unmet dependencies when using apt-get -f install?

Tags: installation, ubuntu-10.04, apt, dependencies

I'm trying to use apt-get to install imagick. Should be simple enough. This is my command.

```
apt-get install imagemagick libmagickcore-dev libmagickwand-dev
```

However instead of installing it keeps bouncing back with this error message

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
nginx-full: Depends: nginx-common (= 1.0.4-1ppa1~lucid) but it is not going to be installed 
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

No worries, so I try `apt-get -f install`

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following extra packages will be installed:
  nginx-common
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  nginx-common
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 38 not upgraded.
2 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0B/59.4kB of archives.
After this operation, 246kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]?
```

Yep let's continue `Y`

But then it gives me this:

```
(Reading database ... 23160 files and directories currently installed.)
Unpacking nginx-common (from .../nginx-common_1.0.4-1ppa1~lucid_all.deb) ...
dpkg: error processing /var/cache/apt/archives/nginx-common_1.0.4-1ppa1~lucid_all.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/etc/ufw/applications.d/nginx', which is also in package nginx 0:1.0.0-0ppa1~lucid
Processing triggers for man-db ...
Processing triggers for ureadahead ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/nginx-common_1.0.4-1ppa1~lucid_all.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I've tried stopping the nginx service. I did an apt-get update, but all to no avail :(

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This does not solve it by ignoring dependencies, but 2 of your packages seem to be claiming ownership of the file /etc/ufw/applications.d/nginx . 
If you move it out of the way (mv /etc/ufw/applications.d/nginx ~/nginx-ufw-tmp), and try the apt-get -f install again, it should not be complaining about this file anymore. Afterwards, you can compare the old and the new /etc/ufw/applications.d/nginx and decide which one you want to keep.
Please note that this is an exceptional situation, you seem to have installed nginx from a ppa source?

Comment: Thanks for that, It worked great! I was trying to upgrade to the latest version of nginx a few weeks back so that must have done it I think. Broke some of the config files for my website though, but got it all sorted now.